# C# - Calling a function in another program over a networked solution

Tags: c#, networking, function, combobox

I have a server and a client program, and they communicate as expected. The only thing is, I have a combo box on the client program, and when this combo box is changed, I want it to call a function on the server program. How would I go about this? I've thought about it for a while, and just can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to establish a communication path between the two programs and send a message in the event of the combo box change.  There are many possible solutions out but a couple of the more popular methods of cross process communication in .Net are

- WCF
- Remoting
- Named Pipes

My personal choice would be to use WCF.  I find it to be less connected and easier to use than Remoting and there are tons of tutorials available on the subject

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcf_bohansen.aspx

Comment: I'm quite new to this, and all this looks rather overwhelming for just running one function. I don't doubt for a second that you are correct and know exactly what you are talking about, but isn't there an easier way using the tcp connection I already have?

Comment: @Alex if you have an existing TCP connection and are already sending data back and forth then you could just invent a message protocal.  Say if the first byte is 0 then do what you're already doing else if the byte is 1 call this specific function, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

I tried JaredPar's solution by getting the client to send a message that started with "6", and get the server to monitor all incoming messages for a message that started with "6". If one did, then it called the function.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is at all web based or has access to the HTTP protocol, another option I would suggest for the client/server model in addition to the excellent ones already suggested by  [Jared Par](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283), is to leverage HTTP through a web service (or similar) for communication.

For example

- ASP.NET [web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx).
- [MVC using Restful architecture](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2007/12/06/aspnet-mvc-using-restful-architecture).
- or even [jQuery/AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) on the front end (or a similar library) if your presentation layer is web based.

Comment: It's not web based but I have it working now. I tried JaredPar's solution by getting the client to send a message that started with "6", and get the server to monitor all incoming messages for a message that started with "6". If one did, then it called the function. Thanks for you're input though.